# What is the importance of changing the strict inequalities in the definition of a limit to weak inequalities.

Tags: limits

What is the importance of the difference between these two?

$$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x)([0 < \lvert x-a \rvert < \delta ] \Rightarrow [\lvert f(x)-L \rvert < \varepsilon ])$$
$$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x)([0 < \lvert x-a \rvert \leq \delta ] \Rightarrow [\lvert f(x)-L \rvert \leq \varepsilon ])$$

Thanks

Comment: They are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume (1). Consider an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Then because $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $k> 0$ such that 
$$0 < \lvert x-a \rvert < k  \Rightarrow \lvert f(x)-L \rvert < \varepsilon $$
In particular, when $\delta=k/2$,
$|x-a| \le \delta$ implies $|x-a| < k$
implying $\lvert f(x)-L \rvert < \varepsilon$
implying $\lvert f(x)-L \rvert \le \varepsilon$. Thus (2) holds.

Conversely, assume (2). Consider an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Then because $\epsilon/2>0$, there exists a $k> 0$ such that 
$$0 < \lvert x-a \rvert \le k  \Rightarrow \lvert f(x)-L \rvert \le \varepsilon/2 $$
In particular, when $\delta=k$,
$|x-a| < \delta$ implies $|x-a| \le \delta$
implying $\lvert f(x)-L \rvert \le \varepsilon/2$
implying $\lvert f(x)-L \rvert < \varepsilon$. Thus (1) holds.

Comment: Thank you, this clears it up for me. That was my general intuition but now I can see how it works out.